WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 123, so returning the closest version found
I have been running some tests a few times a year and I sometimes have to update my chromedriver to match my Google Chrome version. Today was one of those days I tried to run these tests except this time after updating my chromedriver the test still didn't work and I got these warnings and errors.
Starting ChromeDriver 123.0.6312.105 (399174dbe6eff0f59de9a6096129c0c827002b3a-refs/branch-heads/6312@{#761}) on port 53767
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Apr 10, 2024 4:35:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Apr 10, 2024 4:35:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 123, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
Apr 10, 2024 4:35:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 123.
Apr 10, 2024 4:35:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.4.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
16:35:43.557 [main] ERROR  -
16:35:43.561 [main] ERROR  -     Test failed at step: When Sample.y4m is tested
16:35:43.561 [main] ERROR  -     Failed to get a result in time.  Exception thrown Expected condition failed: waiting for presence of element located by: By.cssSelector: pre[id="resultText"] li (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Selenium is referenced in my pom.xml file like so:
<testPlanLibraries>
    <artifact>org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0</artifact>
    <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59</artifact>
    <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:3.141.59</artifact>
</testPlanLibraries>

I have tried to downgrade my google chrome version, but it is not showing up in my add or remove programs to uninstall. I tried deleting it from the Programs directory and installing an older version but that didn't work. I guess there are some remnants of it that I need to remove in the registry which I really don't want to do. So I guess I should try to embrace this and try to use the correct selenium to get this running properly. But I am not sure which version to use and if so how to add it to the pom.xml file.

The version(3.141.59) in use in your code pom.xml is way too old. Use the current latest selenium version for Java binding which is v4.19.1.
Just replace 3.141.59 to 4.19.1 in your xml as below.
<testPlanLibraries>
    <artifact>org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0</artifact>
    <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.19.1</artifact>
    <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:4.19.1</artifact>
</testPlanLibraries>

Also, I don't know if you have <dependency> in your pom.xml. If you have, it should look like below:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.19.1</version>
</dependency>


After changing the pom.xml file with the selenium references, I am still getting the same error messages. I realized now that a different pom.xml file that has no selenium references is the one being compiled and run. How should I reference selenium in that one? I tried adding the dependency like you described but I get these errors.

[ERROR] Steps.java:[34,22] cannot access org.openqa.selenium.HasDownloads
class file for org.openqa.selenium.HasDownloads not found
[ERROR] Steps.java:[36,31] cannot access org.openqa.selenium.federatedcredentialmanagement.HasFederatedCredentialManagement
class file for org.openqa.selenium.federatedcredentialmanagement.HasFederatedCredentialManagement not found
